# Duplicating records in a mysql table intermittently causes statements to hang and not return

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mysql-5.5

We are trying to duplicate existing records in a table: make 10 records out of one. The original table contains 75.000 records, and once the statements are done will contain about 750.000 (10 times as many). The statements sometimes finish after 10 minutes, but many times they never return. Hours later we will receive a timeout. This happens about 1 out of 3 times. We are using a test database where nobody is working on, so there is no concurrent access to the table. I don't see any way to optimise the SQL since to me the EXPLAIN PLAN looks fine.

The database is mysql 5.5 hosted on AWS RDS db.m3.x-large. The CPU load goes up to 50% during the statements.

Question: What could cause this intermittent behaviour? How do I resolve it?

This is the SQL to create a temporary table, make roughly 9 new records per existing record in ct_revenue_detail in the temporary table, and then copy the data from the temporary table to ct_revenue_detail

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AND COPY ROLL-UP RECORDS INTO TABLE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ct_revenue_detail_tmp

SELECT r.month,
          r.period,
          a.participant_eid,
          r.employee_name,
          r.employee_cc,
          r.assignments_cc,
          r.lob_name,
          r.amount,
          r.gp_run_rate,
          r.unique_id,
          r.product_code,
          r.smart_product_name,
          r.product_name,
          r.assignment_type,
          r.commission_pcent,
          r.registered_name,
          r.segment,
          'Y' as account_allocation,
          r.role_code,
          r.product_eligibility,
          r.revenue_core,
          r.revenue_ict,
          r.primary_account_manager_id,
          r.primary_account_manager_name
     FROM ct_revenue_detail r
          JOIN ct_account_allocation_revenue a
             ON a.period = r.period AND a.unique_id = r.unique_id
    WHERE a.period = 3 AND lower(a.rollup_revenue) = 'y';
```

This is the second query. It copies the records from the temporary table back to the ct_revenue_detail TABLE

```
INSERT INTO ct_revenue_detail(month,
                              period,
                              participant_eid,
                              employee_name,
                              employee_cc,
                              assignments_cc,
                              lob_name,
                              amount,
                              gp_run_rate,
                              unique_id,
                              product_code,
                              smart_product_name,
                              product_name,
                              assignment_type,
                              commission_pcent,
                              registered_name,
                              segment,
                              account_allocation,
                              role_code,
                              product_eligibility,
                              revenue_core,
                              revenue_ict,
                              primary_account_manager_id,
                              primary_account_manager_name)
    SELECT month,
          period,
          participant_eid,
          employee_name,
          employee_cc,
          assignments_cc,
          lob_name,
          amount,
          gp_run_rate,
          unique_id,
          product_code,
          smart_product_name,
          product_name,
          assignment_type,
          commission_pcent,
          registered_name,
          segment,
          account_allocation,
          role_code,
          product_eligibility,
          revenue_core,
          revenue_ict,
          primary_account_manager_id,
          primary_account_manager_name
     FROM ct_revenue_detail_tmp;
```

This is the EXPLAIN PLAN of the SELECT:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys          | key          | key_len | ref                                | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref  | ct_period,ct_unique_id | ct_period    | 4       | const                              | 38828 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref  | ct_period,ct_unique_id | ct_unique_id | 5       | optusbusiness_20160802.a.unique_id |   133 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------+
```

This is the definition of ct_revenue_detail:

```
ct_revenue_detail | CREATE TABLE `ct_revenue_detail` (
  `participant_eid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lob_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gp_run_rate` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignments_cc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_cc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `smart_product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignment_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commission_pcent` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `segment` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_allocation` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_code` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_eligibility` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rollup` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revised_amount` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_amount` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_revised_flag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exclude_segment` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revenue_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revenue_core` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revenue_ict` decimal(32,16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_account_manager_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_account_manager_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`,`period`),
  KEY `ct_participant_eid` (`participant_eid`),
  KEY `ct_period` (`period`),
  KEY `ct_employee_name` (`employee_name`),
  KEY `ct_month` (`month`),
  KEY `ct_segment` (`segment`),
  KEY `ct_unique_id` (`unique_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15338782 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (period)
PARTITIONS 120 */ |
```

Edit 29.9: The intermittent behaviour was caused by the omission of a delete SQL statement. If the original table was not deleted before automatically duplicating records. The first time all is fine: we started with 75,000 records and ended up with 750,000 records.
Because the delete statement was missed the next time we already had 750,000 records, and the script would make 7.5M records out of it. That would still work, but the subsequent run trying to make 7.5M into 75M records would fail. 1 in 3 failures. 
We would then try all the scripts manually, and of course then we would delete the table properly, and all would go well. The reason why we didn't see that beforehand was that our application does not output anything when running the SQL.

Comment: anything in the mysql logs? What's your default engine?

Comment: Engine is InnoDB. I turned on the general log and the slow query log, but I don't see any particular interesting info in there. What am I looking for?

Comment: hang on a sec, there are two queries here. It's the second one that's causing trouble right?

Comment: The key here is that the behaviour is INTERMITTENT. I am less concerned about the statement running slow as I am that SOMETIMES it takes 10 minutes, and SOMETIMES it will time out after 2 hrs.

Comment: You are obviously going past some threshold value or tipping point in some of your queries, but since the query is so inefficient (due to undelying problems with the tables) this cannot be avoided all together

Answer (score 1):

The real delay would be with your second query inserting from the temporary table back into the original tables. There are several issues here.

### Sheer amount of data

Looking at your table, there are several columns of `varchar(255)` a conservative estimate would put an average length of your rows at 2kb. That's roughly about 1.5GB that's being copied from one table to another and being moved to different partitions! Partitioning makes reads more efficient but for inserting the engine has to figure out which partition the data should be moved to so it's actually writing to lots of different files instead of sequentially to one file. For spinning disks, this is slow.

### Rebuilding the indexes

One of the biggest costs of inserts is rebuilding the indexes. In your case you have many of them.

```
  KEY `ct_participant_eid` (`participant_eid`),
  KEY `ct_period` (`period`),
  KEY `ct_employee_name` (`employee_name`),
  KEY `ct_month` (`month`),
  KEY `ct_segment` (`segment`),
  KEY `ct_unique_id` (`unique_id`)
```

And some of this indexes like `employee_name` are on `varchar(255)` columns. That means pretty hefty indexes.

### Solution part 1 - Normalize

Your database isn't normalized. Here is a classic example:

primary_account_manager_id varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_account_manager_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,

You should really be having a table called `account_manager` and these two fields should be in that. `primary_account_manager_id` probably should be an integer field. It is only the id that should be in your `ct_revenue_detail` table.

Similarly you really shouldn't have `employee_name`, `registered_name` etc in this table. They should be in separate tables and they should be linked to ct_revenue_detail by foreign keys.

### Solution part 2 - Rethink indexes.

Do you need so many? Mysql only uses one index per table per where clause anyway so some of these indexes are probably never used. Is this one really needed:

```
KEY `ct_unique_id` (`unique_id`)
```

You already have primary key why do you even need another unique column?

Comment: Thanks for that. These are general optimisations on the query, but it doesn't help or explain why there are vast differences in runtimes: 10 minutes vs. does not complete after 2 hours. Have you ever encountered that?

Comment: 1) Unfortunately we cannot normalise because this is a csv import of data from our client. In addition, our software does not support foreign key references.

Comment: 2) I will reexamine the indexes to see if they are used at all.

Comment: rethinking indexes will help you solve part of the problem only but yeah, it might keep you from going over the unknown tipping point. I don't understand this bit: "In addition, our software does not support foreign key references"

Answer (score 1):

**Indexes for the SELECT**: For

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ct_revenue_detail r
    JOIN ct_account_allocation_revenue a
         ON a.period = r.period AND a.unique_id = r.unique_id
    WHERE a.period = 3 AND lower(a.rollup_revenue) = 'y';
```

`a` needs `INDEX(period, rollup_revenue)` in either order.  However, you also need to declare `rollup_revenue` to have a `..._ci` collation *and* avoiding the column in a function.  That is change `lower(a.rollup_revenue) = 'y'` to `a.rollup_revenue = 'y'`.

`r` needs `INDEX(period, unique_id)` in either order.  But, as e4c5 mentioned, if `unique_id` is really "unique" *in this table*, then take advantage of such.

**Bulkiness** is a problem when shoveling data around.

- `decimal(32,16)` takes 16 bytes and gives you precision and range that are probably unnecessary.  Consider `FLOAT` (4 bytes, ~7 significant digits, adequate range) or `DOUBLE` (8 bytes, ~16 significant digits, adequate range).
- `month int(11)` takes 4 bytes.  If that is just a value 1..12, then use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte).
- `DEFAULT NULL` -- I suspect most columns will never be `NULL`; if so, say `NOT NULL` for them.
- `amount_revised_flag varchar(255)` -- if that is really a "flag", such as "yes"/"no", then use an `ENUM` and save lots of space.
- It is uncommon to have both an id and a name in the same table (see `primary_account_manager*`); that is usually relegated to a "normalization table".
- "Normalize" (already mentioned by @e4c5).

**HASH partitioning**

Hash partitioning is virtually useless.  Unless you can justify it (preferably with a benchmark), I recommend removing partitioning.  [*More discussion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/).

Adding or removing partitioning usually involves changing the indexes.  Please show us the main queries so we can help you build suitable indexes (especially composite indexes) for the queries.

Comment: We chose the Hash partitioning to be able to delete records by period, which is the month of the data. For every "calculation" our application does we first clear the data for that period, and then reinsert it into ct_revenue_detail. With the hash partitioning we can just truncate the data for that period rather than deleting the data.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two "periods" in a single Hash?

Comment: Periods are effectively months. I have 120 partitions, and to my understanding that means that the first 120 months will land in partitions p0 - p119, and only the data in month 121 will land in p0 again. We don't actually ever expect 120 periods of data in the system. I could be wrong with the hash function, though.

Comment: Do you `DELETE` or `DROP` the partition after 120 days?  Do you ever need a "range" of periods?  If so, Hash will always look at all partitions.